# Continuing alternation of colors in multiple tables

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using CSS [nth-of-type](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) property, I am able to alternate the colors of the rows in a table. Suppose the colors are grey and white.

Is it possible to alternate the colors of the rows in distinct tables as a whole (w/out the use of JS) ? Meaning that if the first table ends with grey, the next table should start with white.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the HTML structure and the page is static (no server-side is building the table).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 250px;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
  background: lightgrey;
}

tr:nth-of-type(even) td {
  background: white;
}

td span {
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row #1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row #2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row #3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- would like the colors to continue from where it left off -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row #4 <span>(would like it to be white)</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row #5 <span>(would like it to be gray)</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You would need Javascript to do that. CSS can't do it for you...not even with `nth-of`` selectors

Comment: If the page is static, then you know beforehand how many rows each table contains, right? In your example, the first table has three rows, so you can target the `table:nth-of-type(2)` so that it starts with white.

Comment: @MrLister The table gets updated manually every so often, so yes I would know the number of rows of each table. Manually changing the CSS property according to each table would be more of a pain however. Thanks though. If it can't be done easily with CSS, then it can't be done. Oh well.